# How to Get an image and text to align next to each other

Tags: html, css

Very new to this, I'm trying to get an image and a text to align next to each other in the header, but it wont move. The text just sits at the bottom of the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome_homepage_css.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Text Here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

```
.header .text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: rgb(26,30,170);
}

.header .image
.header .text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Don’t put them in different div you can use span for that

Comment: Simple You have missed a comma "," after ".header .image"

https://codepen.io/tharakauka/pen/BEjdvG

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<span class="image">
        <img src="logo.png">
</span>
<span class="text">
         <h1>Text Here</h1>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .header{
     display:inline-block;
     width:100px;
   }
  .text{
     display:inline-block;
     width:100px;
   }
```

for the width give the amount you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Simply add float:left to image and text parent class.

```
Suggested CSS

.header{
  float:left;
}

.image, .text {
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<p><img style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;" src="file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/search-icon.png" width="100" />Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque convallis. Nunc vel libero orci.<br style="clear: both;" /></p>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take everyones tips and get it to work, i changed my divs to span as recommended. but had to add in vertical-align using length to get it where I wanted it. Many thanks!

```
        <span class="image">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </span>
        <span class="text">
            <h1>Text Here</h1>
        </span>
```

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) enough for content alignment.

Also add `justify-content` to space the items how you want it:

`justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly;`

and align-items to vertically align them how you like:

`align-items: stretch | flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline;`

Learn flexbox and you will never worry about this again.

```css
.header .text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: rgb(26,30,170);
}

.header {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Text Here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```